# Nginx configuration for friendly urls

Tags: nginx, configuration, friendly-url

Well Hello,

I'm trying to create friendly urls with nginx.

This is my configuration so far:

```
server {
    listen 80;
    server_name mysite.gr;
    rewrite ^(.*) http://www.mysite.gr$1 permanent;
```

}

first block for urls without www

```
server {
    listen 80;
    server_name www.mysite.gr;
    root /var/www/mysite.gr;
    index index.asp;

    access_log /var/log/nginx/access.log;
    error_log /var/log/nginx/error.log;

    client_max_body_size 10M;

    location / {
            try_files $uri $uri/ /index.asp?$query_string;
    }

    proxy_set_header        Host            $host;
```

}

And that is the main configuration.
When root and index directives are enabled browser downloads the file.

When i comment index directive i get 403 Forbidden and nginx error log sais "directory index of "/var/www/mysite.gr/" is forbidden".

When i comment both root and index i get 500 error and error log sais "1 rewrite or internal redirection cycle while internally redirecting to "/index.asp"

What i want to do is 
www.mysite.gr/pertners to point to www.mysite.gr/index.asp?q=pertners
www.mysite.gr/pertners/the_partner to point to www.mysite.gr/index.asp?q=pertners&p=the_partner

any suggestions?

By the way *.asp i use Apache::ASP with mod_perl.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Even thought @NexWarner's answer led me to a dead end his/her link was food for thought to me. So, i changed his search a bit and after a few tries i came up with the following configuration.

```
server {
    listen 80;
    server_name www.mysite.gr;
    root /var/www/mysite.gr;
    index index.asp;

    access_log /var/log/nginx/access.log;
    error_log /var/log/nginx/error.log;

    client_max_body_size 10M;

    #Case we call www.mysite.gr
    #no file so nginx serves controller.asp of corse with empty uri.
    #we do not check for folder($uri/) cause this is the root folder so index.asp will be loaded.
    location = / {
            try_files $uri /controller.asp?uri=$uri;
    }

    #case we call www.mysite.gr/foo or www.mysite.gr/foo/bar
    #$uri is no file neither folder so nginx serves controller.asp with uri=/foo/bar
    location / {
            try_files $uri $uri/ /controller.asp?uri=$uri;
    }

    #ask nginx to serve static file because without this if we read the uri in controller.asp we get .js and .css files too.
    location ~* \.(js|css|jpg|jpeg|gif|png|svg|svgz|ico|pdf|html|htm)$ {
            expires      30d;
   }

    #Finaly i think that this location directive did the magic for me. 
    #we ask nginx to pass to the Apache server everything that is an asp script.
    location ~* \.asp$ {
            proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:8080;
            proxy_redirect off;
    }

    #Apache will use this Host to determine which name-based VirtualHost will handle the request
    proxy_set_header        Host            $host;
    #Normaly Apache will log the incoming request as coming from nginx.
```

}

After that we just read the uri in controller.asp and include any other file we want:

```
my $Params = $Request->Params();
$Response->Include('foo.asp') if $Params->{uri} eq 'foo';
$Response->Include('foo.asp?q=bar') if $Params->{uri} eq 'foo/bar'; #or whatever equal you like.
```

So, i think @NexWarner's answer was the start of a solution for me.
Thanks, @NexWarner.

Answer (score 1):

In this case, you will need to use Nginx as a reverse proxy. That is to serve static content from Nginx and dynamic content (ASP) from your proxy server. A sample configuration would be like below.

```
server {
    listen 80;
    server_name www.mysite.gr;
    root /var/www/mysite.gr;
    index index.html;

    location / {
        try_files $uri $uri/ @proxy;
    }

    location ~* \.(js|css|jpg|jpeg|gif|png|svg|ico|pdf|html|htm)$ {
        expires     30d;
    }

    location ~* \.asp$ {
        proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:8000; # Host and port of where your ASP is running
        include /etc/nginx/proxy_params; # Location and availability depend on your Nginx setup
    }

    location @proxy {
        proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:8000;
        include /etc/nginx/proxy_params;
    }
}
```

http://www.google.com/search?q=nginx+reverse+proxy+apache

Comment: thanks for your answer. I will try tell you what will happen.

Comment: Im still at the same point. Now i get again 403 forbidden.
The configuration you suggest seem to be like mine before i asked to add friendly urls. So if i'm right this configuration passes everything accept js css and images to apache. 
That said i do not want to use the apache rewrite engine, i asked to do it with the try_files directive but still nothing happened.
Thanks for the response thought.